# Can Google Site Search be used in the website using virtual IP address?

Tags: php, google-custom-search, virtual-ip-address

I'd like to know whether I'm able to use Google Site Search in my web site, which is using virtual IP address without public domain and is providing a service only for the company employees.
I'm using PHP, Html and Scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: exactly what is a "virtual ip"? But in any case, if your site is not reachable from the outside world, how do you expect google to be able to reach your site and spider it?

Comment: there's always: https://www.google.ca/work/search/products/gsa.html

Comment: Thanks! Marc. It could not be possible as I guessed. I will try to get either a public domain or a php search engine which can be installed in my website

Comment: Oh! Google Search Appliance. I have ever seen it before. I'll check it. Thank you so much!